# Animação de texto em Javascript não funciona corretamente

Tags: javascript, animação

No meu arquivo HTML, tenho a seguinte tag:

`<h1 id="title">Desenvolvedor </h1>`

Com o Javascript, eu quero fazer uma animação em loop acrescentando outros textos letra por letra, removendo-os da mesma forma e mudando o texto antes de acrescentar novamente. O código está assim:

```
const title = document.getElementById("title");
const stacks = ["Front-End", "Back-End", "Full Stack"];
const speed = 200;
let stackIndex = 0;
let i = 0;

function addChar() {
  setTimeout(() => {
    title.innerHTML += stacks[stackIndex].charAt(i);
    i++;
    typeWriter(stackIndex);
  }, speed);
}

function deleteChar() {
  setTimeout(() => {
    title.innerHTML = title.innerHTML.slice(0, -1);
    
    if (title.innerText.length > 13) {
      deleteChar();
    } else {
      if (stackIndex > 1) {
        i = 0;
        stackIndex = 0;
        typeWriter(stackIndex);
      }

      i = 0;
      typeWriter(stackIndex++);
    }

  }, speed);
}

function typeWriter(stackIndex) {
  if (i < stacks[stackIndex].length) {
    addChar();
  } else {
    deleteChar();
  }
}
```

Como é possível ver [**nesse gif**](https://i.imgur.com/Bqpi4LN.gif), acrescentar os textos e mudar seus valores funcionou normalmente, mas, na hora de resetar os valores de **stackIndex** e **i** e iniciar a animação novamente, começa a apresentar bugs, mesmo que em teoria esteja repetindo todo o código do zero.
Como corrigir esse erro? Existe alguma forma mais prática de fazer essa animação?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Então basicamente aí faltou você reinicializar a contagem da variável `stackIndex` que verifica a quantidade de elementos do **array**. No seu **`else/if`** na função `deleteChar()` você também colocou algumas lógicas desnecessárias, acredito que tenha pensado que por ali seria o local para reinicializar a contagem da variável:

```js
const title = document.getElementById("title");
const stacks = ["Front-End", "Back-End", "Full Stack"];
const speed = 200;
let stackIndex = 0;
let i = 0;

function addChar() {
  setTimeout(() => {
    if (stackIndex < 3) {     // Se não percorreu todo array continua escrevendo
      title.innerHTML += stacks[stackIndex].charAt(i);
      i++;
      typeWriter(stackIndex);
    } else {                  // Se já percorreu tudo, recomeça a contagem
      stackIndex = 0;
      typeWriter(stackIndex);
    }
  }, speed);
}

function deleteChar() {
  setTimeout(() => {
    if (title.innerText.length > 13) {
      title.innerHTML = title.innerHTML.slice(0, -1);
      deleteChar();
    } else {
      i = 0;
      typeWriter(stackIndex++);
    }
  }, speed);
}

function typeWriter(_stackIndex) {
  if (i < stacks[_stackIndex].length) {
    addChar();
  } else {
    deleteChar();
  }
}

typeWriter(stackIndex);
```

```html
<h1 id="title">Desenvolvedor </h1>
```

Comment: Ao(s) nobre(s) colega(s) que negativaram a resposta, poderiam explanar o pq? Para que assim eu possa melhorar, só com negativação parece não haver nenhum motivo aparente, a não ser o gosto pessoal de negativar, o que descredibiliza o site! Ainda mais : )

Comment: Funcionou direitinho, muito obrigado!! 